# Java multi-threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an object which contains data, I am queuing an Action (interface with a method that can be executed) with this object (the action will use object's data inside its method), and the queued Actions are going to be executed from another thread.

I'd like to lock the object after sending it to the action queue (so from my main thread).

Because I don't want object's data being changed before the other thread has processed it through the action queue.

And I'd like the object to be unlocked, once the action queue will be processed, from the other thread.

Code illustration:

```
// THREAD 1
final Object object = getObjectFromSomeWhere(); 

// lock the object here

concurrentActionQueue.add(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
          // will be executed from THREAD 2
          // do something with object

          //unlock here once the data is processed

        }
```

You would say I could sent a copy of the object to the Action, but my object is containing very big data and copying is taking to much time so I can't.

Is there a way to do this without hardcoding lock() and unlock() methods to my object ?

Comment: consumer producer pattern maybe ? here is a very simple(not the best) [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm) to start with

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock the execution of all main thread, you can use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

```
// THREAD 1
final Object object = getObjectFromSomeWhere(); 

final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

concurrentActionQueue.add(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
          // will be executed from THREAD 2
          // do something with object

          latch.countDown();   
        }
}

latch.await();
```

If you want to lock the object data from being changed from other thread, but leave execution of thread available, you need to do it inside your `Object` class. I believe it is not an Object. For example, you can pass the reference to the `Thread`, that have an access to the object, and check inside it `Thread.currentThread() == mAllowedThread;` to know is this thread allowed to modify an object.

Also, you can use some OO-way to deal with that, for example make you object has package-local setters and pass a wrapper that has access to setters to the action. It hard to say what is a solution, because I don't see your actual problem. Hope some of my suggestions can help you as well.

Comment: My problem is that the moment when I sent my data (object) to the action queue, it is in a good format . But the data is changed persistently and the action could be executed at a moment when data is no longer in a good format (while being modified from thread 1) which is dangerous. My thread 2 is a renderer and it requires well ordered data for its meshes.

Comment: what do you mean under the "lock/unlock" object ? how should other thread behave when it try to change the object ?

Comment: Well there is more than one possibility, one is the other thread could have to wait until the unlock before doing any modification to the data . Or I could hardcode something that will put in queue every modification occured to the data while its locked, and execute when its no longer locked.

Answer (score 0):

Only common refrence between threads is your object hence to achieve locking you have to modify your object. If you don't want to modify your object you can write one helper class which will use countdown latch to execute the task. And pass this helper class reference among all your threads.
See if this is what you are looking for -

```
final YourObject object = getObjectFromSomeWhere();

class HelperObject {
YourObject object;
public HelperObject(YourObject object){
this.object = object;
}
 final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
   public void countDown(){
     latch.countDown(); 
   }

   public void await(){
    latch.await();
   }
}

 concurrentActionQueue.add(new Action() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
      // will be executed from THREAD 2
      HelperObject helperObj;// do something with object

      helperObj.countDown();   
    }
}
```